# Restoring from old paper Mycelium Wallet Backup

Tags: mycelium-wallet

I have an old Mycelium Wallet Backup on paper, created July 2014, Mycelium Wallet 1.2.12., Backup Format Mycelium Backup 1.0. It used a 15-character password + checksum character, which I have.

It also lists Bitcoin address, and Encrypted Private Key - both in QR-code and in string of characters.

How do I go about restoring this wallet to a current wallet, be it Mycelium or some other one?

Answer (score 1):

Answering to myself: at least MyCelium can scan the Mycelium Backup 1.0 PDF paper wallet. However, one must tap the QR code symbol to change to "Legacy (P2PKH)". After scanning the paper wallet QR-code, Mycelium then asks for the 15-character password + checksum character.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest asking this question on the mycelium issue topic. Either for [android](https://github.com/mycelium-com/wallet-android/issues) or [ios](https://github.com/mycelium-com/wallet-ios/issues). Generally for the backups in that time bip39 was a main standard as per https://walletsrecovery.org/ - mycelium was supporting [WIF](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Wallet_import_format) (wallet import format). Knowing the derivation paths, one can recover from it in the wallet that supports WIF (like electrum?).

Comment: It would seem this is not WIF, which seems to be a 64 character string. Rather, this is a 62 character encrypted private key.

Comment: I do have the 15-character password for the encrypted key, but I do not understand how to go about decrypting it as per the second page of the paper wallet instructions.

(Parsing the QR Code, Decoding the 3 Header Bytes, AES Key Derivation, Decrypting the Private Key, Generating the Bitcoin Address, Verifying the Checksum"

I do have the Bitcoin Address related to this Private Key, and therefore know there is some bitcoin there.

Answer (score 0):

In Mycelium there should be an option to restore a backup. Inside this restoration feature there should be an option to recover legacy backups (the one you have) once you have selected that you scan the qr code of the encrypted private key. The next thing you get presented with is the prompt to enter your passcode (the 15 digit one). I believe though, you need to enter 16 characters. All of those characters are alphabetical ones. the 16th digit is the checksum character (this is also a character ranging from A-Z if you have not written that down). It should be succesful after the correct passphrase was entered.